# Xna, writing XML </Asset> end element

Tags: xna, c#, xml

got another question here. Its not about actually writing/reading files in XML, i already know how to-do this. But rather something that has bugged me for awhile. 
Ok, so when i write out my files, they look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent>
 <Asset Type="ProjectWitch.Animation">
      <Filename>C:\Users\Daniel Randell\Desktop\Project Witch\Project Witch (MAIN)\Project_Witch (MAIN)\Project_Witch (MAIN)Content\player.png</Filename>
      <CurrentFrame>0</CurrentFrame>
      <Number_Of_Frames>1</Number_Of_Frames>
      <Max_Time_Per_Frame>0</Max_Time_Per_Frame>
      <Animate_Once>0</Animate_Once>
      <Using_Image>1</Using_Image>
      <Rect>
        0    166  64   58   
      </Rect>
      <Vector2>
        12   12   
      </Vector2>
      <Rect>
        81   71   51   59   False
        80   71   13   43   True 
        121  71   12   22   True 
        130  82   7    41   True 
        89   63   11   23   True 
      </Rect>
 </Asset Type="ProjectWitch.Animation">
```

As you can see the problem, it should write out at the end:

```
      </Asset>
 </XnaContent>
```

But it's always writes out the:

```
 </Asset Type="ProjectWitch.Animation">
```

Its a bit annoying to keep having to look into the XML files and deleting this, so i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong?

Saving Code:
http://pastebin.com/yyC3q3aS

Thanks for any help :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("Asset Type=\"ProjectWitch.Animation\"");
```

That is not how you add an attribute using `XmlTextWriter`. I think the correct would be:

```cs
writer.WriteStartElement("Asset");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", "ProjectWitch.Animation");
```

And make sure you're not missing any `WriteEndElement` call.

By the way, the most recent and recommended method of handling XML in C# is the [XDocument API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). You should consider making the switch, because it works at an higher level, and you don't need to manually *start* and *end* your tags. Example:

```cs
// Create content
var root = new XElement("Player",         // Create root node
    new XAttribute("Id", "1"),            // Add attribute
    new XElement("Name", "Jon Skeet")     // Add child node with value
);

// Save to disk
XDocument document = new XDocument(root);
document.Save("file.xml");
```

Which would produce the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Player Id="1">
    <Name>Jon Skeet</Name>
</Player>
```

---

**Edit 1**

> Just wondering though with using the XDocument API, as you can see i'm saving alot of data, more importantly the Rectangles & Vector2s. Its quite fiddly i find to save these currently and i don't want to have a new element for each field i.e X/Y/Width/Height but rather like it is currently. Is that possible using the XDocument Api?

In the comments you raised concerns about being able to do something like this:

```
  <Rect>
    81   71   51   59
    80   71   13   43
    121  71   12   22
    130  82   7    41
    89   63   11   23
  </Rect>
```

You were using methods such as `XmlTextWriter.WriteValue` and `XmlTextWriter.WriteWhiteSpace` to do this incremental sort of writing. As far as I know you can't write to an `XElement` this way, but coupled with a `StringBuilder` object (which you can reuse) it's easy to get a similar behavior:

```cs
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // Create only once

stringBuilder.Clear();
foreach(var r in rectangles)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(
        String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height)
    );
}
var rectElement = new XElement("Rect", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

The `StringBuilder` has both `Append` and `AppendLine` methods which will still allow you to construct your values similarly to what you were doing before.

But there are many other ways to do this, some more efficient, others easier. Personally, I would do:

```cs
public static string SerializeRectangle(Rectangle r)
{
    return String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
}

var rectElement = new XElement("Rect", String.Join("\n", rectangles.Select(SerializeRectangle)));
```

---

**Edit 2**

> Last comment, in terms of reading the file, how would that work?

Here's a simple loading example without error handling. In a real scenario you should always check if `Element` or `Attribute` returns null:

```cs
var document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var player = document.Element("Player");
int id = int.Parse(player.Attribute("Id").Value);
string name = player.Element("Name").Value;
```

If there's more than one element with a certain name, use the `Elements` method instead to retrieve all of them at once.

Comment: Thanks again Dave! Just wondering though with using the XDocument API, as you can see i'm saving alot of data, more importantly the Rectangles & Vector2s. Its quite fiddly i find to save these currently and i don't want to have a new element for each field i.e X/Y/Width/Height but rather like it is currently. Is that possible using the XDocument Api?

Comment: Sure I don't see any limitations in using XDocument. There's two options. Either you save them as attributes, e.g. `<Rectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="100" />`. Or you serialize/deserialize them into string, e.g. `<Rectangle>0,0,100,100</Rectangle>` and doing a `string.Split(',')` when reading it back.

Comment: Just looked again at your example, and just in case the previous comment wasn't clear enough, I'll edit in my post a little example of how you could proceed.

Comment: Thanks again :), Really liking XDocument already, a-lot more straight-forward to use.

Comment: Quickly, last comment, in terms of reading the file, how would that work?

Comment: Top hint David: You can write that out directly to `XmlWriter` too, it's bad practice to round-trip a `StringBuilder` in this case - with `StringBuilder` you land up with maybe 1 or 2 extra strings in memory; `XmlWriter` won't use any more than you write to it (see: `WriteString`).

Comment: Check again, another edit.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson Sorry, but I think I'm a bit lost on the point you're trying to make. I'm not arguing efficiency here, just the increased ease of use of XDocument vs XmlWriter. The StringBuilder was an alternative to adapt his repeated WriteValue behavior to the XDocument API. What were you suggesting instead?

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I.e. writing directly to the `XmlWriter` is what he was already doing in his example.

Comment: So using your suggested method David, i currently get the following;  http://pastebin.com/aMwkTYVJ. It seems that its writing the asset end element before it gets to the rect/vector2. Unsure why though, seems correct to me.

Comment: @DavidGouveia your code example with the `StringBuilder` is completely do-able without the `StringBuilder` - maybe a few more lines, less elegant and less clear. I have never seen it in games, but in enterprise software I have seen 'death by 1000 strings': hang dumps with a ridiculous amount of strings. Strings are **very** broken in .Net: just treat them with utmost care - if you can stream directly into a file: do that instead. Coincidentally, you can have multiple `XText` instances in one `XElement`.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson Alright. I've never tested adding multiple XText instances, but I am guessing they'll be concatenated, which would serve this purpose.

Comment: @Danran Strange. I run your example here and the output was correct.

Comment: Got it slightly better, http://pastebin.com/5zy1xa3v 
Still not perfect, does seem to be when the rect/vector array comes into play that things start to mess up.

Comment: @Daran That looks right to me. You're getting the line breaks added by AppendLine(). You could switch to Append() instead and do them manually.

Comment: @DavidGouveia I only take the time to improve your input because I think you have the potential :).

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I am aware that there are many ways to do this (although I don't know all the alternatives), some more efficient, others easier to use. Check my edit, that's how I would do it personally, but I kinda like LINQ and functional programming. :-P

Comment: @DavidGouveia code first, optimize later right? (I tend to get fixated on performance, but I work on a server - so it's an occupational hazard).

Comment: @JonathanDickinson Yes, I guess I prefer keeping things clean, and optimizing when needed..